# How I can resolve exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOT_ISSUE

Tags: java, exception, java-11

I got exception `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOT_ISSUE` when I try to run my application. I use Java 11.

What does it exception (NOT_ISSUE) mean? Maybe somebody has experience with that because I can't find some information about it.

Full log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOT_ISSUE

    at com.epam.reportportal.junit5.ReportPortalExtension.<clinit>(ReportPortalExtension.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.registerExtension(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.createRegistryFrom(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ExtensionUtils.populateNewExtensionRegistryFromExtendWithAnnotation(ExtensionUtils.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the `ReportPortalExtension.java` source file has a so-called static initializer which is referencing (as in, setting the field, or more likely reading the field) called `NOT_ISSUE`. As in, there is some code somewhere that e.g. contains:

```
public static final LocalDate NOT_ISSUE = LocalDate.of(1800, 1, 1);
```

(It doesn't have to a be a LocalDate, the error doesn't tell you what the type is. All we know is, it can't be a compile time constant, so it's either not a primitive or String type, or it is not being initialized with a constant value), but, the class file of whatever contains that field no longer has it, or doesn't yet have it.

Basically, you've got a version mismatch. That ReportPortalExtension method was written and compiled against a version of whatever contains that field, and you also have that class in your classpath, but a different version that does *not* have this field.

Class load errors are a bit hard to fully disentangle. It's possible that line 82 of ReportPortalExtension isn't the problem at all, but that this is the first time any code running in the VM touches a class, and *that* class has the problem. You only get the most detailed error once, so double check your logs for it. Alternatively, just go search-all through your code and find `NOT_ISSUE`. Then check which class contains this field, and then figure out why you have a version problem there.

Comment: To back this up, the access from the static initializer can be found [here](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-junit5/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/epam/reportportal/junit5/ReportPortalExtension.java#L82). And the field was added to `Launch` in [this changeset](https://github.com/reportportal/client-java/commit/36c1624da17694fc2355ab0f628b2f1cc8a35c96#diff-9ace5e815fa8e1f5a0aaebd0c7dd29bc11c12a344ed0c6f4d3eb6456a8d96471), so the error will occur when using an older version.